# Where is the numpy data stored?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

In python, If only import torch (but not import numpy), "torch.numpy()" can still work. Is that means the numpy data can be stored and displayed without numpy package? Where is the numpy data stored and how does it display (without numpy package)?

example codes:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a = a.numpy()
print(a)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch uses NumPy internally. You don't need to manually import everything a package uses, that is one of the core principles of modules. It's still an object of the same NumPy class and you need to have NumPy installed for it to work, otherwise you would get an import error, just that the import happens in one of PyTorch's files, rather than your own.